# Prove or disprove that this is a polyhedron.

Tags: optimization, proof-writing

Is $$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; x^2+y^2 \leq 1, x -5y=0\},$$ a polyhedron?

I know that the unit disk, $$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; x^2+y^2 \leq 1, x \geq 0, y \geq 0\},$$ is not a polyhedron. How would I use that in this situation? Thanks.

Comment: $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; x^2+y^2 \leq 1, x -5y=0\},$ is intersection of a disk and a line.  So it is a line segment.  Compare that to the definition of "polyhedron".

Comment: It's a polyhedron of dimension 1 ;)

Comment: @GEdgar So I believe it is not a polyhedron.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ So not a polyhedron..

Comment: You should start by writing down the definition of the notion of a "polyhedron" used in your book.

Comment: The definition is:
Let $$A ∈ \mathbb{R}^{mn}$$ and $$b ∈ \mathbb{R}^m$$. The set $${x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n | Ax ≥ b}$$ is called a polyhedron.

Comment: @Sania And this should be a part of your question, not a comment. In other words, a polyhedron for you is the solution set of finitely many nonstrict linear inequalities.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I already indicated some constraints in an answer. Meanwhile, it is not clear that matrix multiplication has any meaning for this OP

Comment: @WillJagy Oh, I didn't see it. Then, it is a lost cause.....

Answer (score 2):

Is $$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \; ; \; \; - \frac{5}{\sqrt{26}} \leq x \leq \frac{5}{\sqrt{26}} \; , \; \; \; x -5y=0\},$$ a polyhedron?

Comment: It is not I believe.

Comment: Can you help explain to me? I do not quite understand why.

Comment: @Sania I have no idea what your text might allow as a polyhedron. So, two things: recommend you carefully draw the figure on graph paper, actual paper; next, give a quality version of the definition of polyhedron that is being used. The main thing is to draw the figure.

Comment: The definition is:
Let $$A ∈ \mathbb{R}^{mn}$$ and $$b ∈ \mathbb{R}^m$$. The set $${x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n | Ax ≥ b}$$ is called a polyhedron.

Comment: @Sania in that case, it is a polyhedron; it can be described exactly as the set of points in the plane that satisfy some inequality constraints and some equality constraints. I already gave you those in the style of your original question

Comment: but the unit disk is not a polyhedron, so how is this a polyhedron?

Comment: @Sania get some graph paper and draw a picture.